# How to start use ElasticSearch in terminal CentOS?

Tags: linux, centos, elasticsearch

I want to create a new index to ElasticSearch via command line in CentOS 6.5:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/typeahead/
```

How to start elasticSearch service?
I tried:

```
service elasticsearch
start elasticsearch
```

Also I tried:

```
cd elasticsearch-1.3.9/
[~/elasticsearch-1.3.9]# cd bin
[~/elasticsearch-1.3.9/bin]# ./elasticsearch -f
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming elasticsearch is setup correctly via the RPM then `sudo service elasticsearch start` should do the trick.